# Two Stage Bipolar Transistor Amplifier Design

Tags: ltspice

I was asked to get a 1V output on the two stage bipolar transistor amplifier circuit ,but the sine wave looks kind of messed up , how do i fix it , what do i need to change ?[image]

you can only change V15749 voltage source/capacitors and resistors to any value

Comment: What are the actual constraints? Do you have to use 1 V? Does the output have to produce 1V peak to peak? Because, if so, that's not happening. Do you have to use an emitter follower as the output? Do you have to use an AC-grounded CE amplifier? What's the input source's peak to peak? What are ***all*** of the constraints and freedoms in design?

Comment: none,no,yes,no,no,yes,can only change V15479 voltage source ,capacitors and resistors

Comment: In your design spec clarify requirements for voltage gain, input impedance and output impedance.

Comment: Why is V1 only 1V? Is that a requirement? That is not enough headroom to design a workable amplifier using garden variety discrete BJT's. At least I wouldn't know how to begin to do it.

Comment: @mkeith you can change the v154719 voltage source and resistor/capacitor to any value

Comment: Just to start, increase VCC to 10 V. Then increase R3 until the DC voltage at E2 is mid-rail (in other words, VCC/2 which is 5V in this case). This will at least get your DC bias somewhat reasonable. Maybe change v154719 to 0V while you do the DC adjustments.

Comment: You are over driving the input adding a small Re in series like 10 to 50 Ohm will help greatly. Your Vb is too high at 67% , try 10% of Vcc

Comment: If you get stuck https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443108/class-a-amplifier-design-emitter-resistance-voltage-drop/443115?r=SearchResults&s=9%7C0.0000#443115

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Why else would we be constrained to only changing R and C values? We don't hand out homework solutions here.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson u can change voltage source too

Comment: @Antony Get rid of every part in there except for R1 through R4 and Q1 (and a power supply.) That circuit has two central concepts you need to worry about: (1) It's DC quiescent operating point; and, (2) It's behavior when presented with an AC signal at its input. Can you just solve (1)??? That's all. Just design it to sit there at a useful DC operating point without any signal at all. It's just four resistors and a BJT. That's al. Can you work that part out?

Comment: I doubt if he can get it to work at Vcc= 1V

Comment: @mkeith thank you very much , it looks like an actually sine wave 1vpp ty

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two big problems that are preventing you from being able to fine tune your circuit.

First, Vcc is too low (at 1V). You can start off by changing Vcc to around 10V (you can tune it more later). Vcc is the same as V1. So just change V1 to 10 VDC.

Second, the DC bias point of the circuit is off. R1, R2, R3 and R4 all effect the DC bias point, but the easiest thing is to change R3 to a much higher value. Just adjust it upwards until the DC voltage at E2 is around Vcc/2.

While you are adjusting the DC bias point, it will be better if there is no AC signal present. So temporarily set V15749 to 0 V output.

Once the DC point is set, you can experiment with other changes. Slowly increase the amplitude of V15749. Check the gain, check the frequency response, etc. If you change VCC, you may need to fine tune one or more of R1-R4 again. These resistors effect DC operating point and also gain.